# How I can add validation for text filed should not be null the text filed is written in JS

Tags: javascript

How I can add validation for the input type= text should not be null the input text is written in JS, not in HTML. the validation should show an alert if it is null before insert in DB.

The code in JS

```
function add_more()
  {
     var tbl = '';
     tbl += '<tr id="'+i+'">';
     tbl += '<td><input  type="checkbox" value_of_i="'+i+'"  value="option1"     id="check_id'+i+'"    class="form-check-input checkbox_item checkk"></td>';
     tbl += '<td><input  type="text"     value_of_i="'+i+'"  name="c_emp_id[]"   id="c_emp_id'+i+'"    class="input-w checkbox_item"                  oninput="get_group('+i+')">';
     tbl += '<input      type="hidden"   value_of_i="'+i+'"  name="h_id[]"       id="h_id'+i+'"        class="inputData checkbox_item"/></td>';
     tbl += '</tr>';

      $("#t_body").append(tbl);


     i =i +1;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry Karl what is tagged irrelevant?

Comment: Originally you had a `python` tag on this question; I removed it.

Comment: Got it, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can write if conditional

```
<input class="SOMECLASS" />
<button onclick="if(document.querySelectorAll('.SOMECLASS')[0].value==null){alert()}" >SAVE</button>
```